# How to use an AngularJS module constant in the source attribute of a script tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security

I have some constants defined in my app like so:

```
angular.module('MyModule')

.constant('myConstant', {
    'userId': '0000',
    'playerId': '1111'
});
```

I'd like to use them in a script URL like so:

```
<script ng-src="http://domain.com/{{myConstant.userId}}/{{myConstant.playerId}}"></script>
```

I'm aware that [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) disallows this type of interpolation, so I've tried using a scope function to return sanitized tokens (using Controller As syntax):

```
{{ctrlAlias.getUserId()}}

ctrlAlias.getUserId = function ($sce) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(ctrlAlias.ctrlVar.userId);
};
```

This is apparently wrong, though. It returns the same error:

> Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.

Is this sort of tokenization feasible in a script source, and what's the right way to handle it? Should I be employing a service to build the entire source URL instead? I'd rather not use Grunt's string replacement in this case.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: you can to load your script with a dinamic load function, like this examples: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml You could to use with a $timeout() to decouple load from angular digest

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for an Angular solution.

Comment: I don't think you should have an issue if you pass the full URL to $sce. I have some code that does this for an iframe without issue. I don't think it's real clear what you are passing to `trustAsResourceUrl`

Comment: https://github.com/urish/angular-load is an angular solution.

Comment: This isn't a dynamic load question. It's about using constants in various places, including script URLs.

Comment: Here is an example that covers pretty much what I ended up doing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24163343/1078110

Comment: @MatthewGreen True, but that's not what I'm after here. Consider it an exploration of another tool in the belt.

Comment: Yes, I know... I'm trying to see other alternatives to $sce problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the userId to the $sce.trustAsResourceUrl function.

The way trustAsResourceUrl works is that it creates an alias to a url that you may later reference in the ng-src attribute.

This will probably work:

```
$scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://domain.com/' + myConstant.userId + '/' + myConstant.playerId

<script ng-src="{{url}}"></script>
```