# Angular URL SRC in iframe desnt show up

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe

I try to set up an iframe with src to youtube. The url inside an iframe is invisivble, when you inspect element in the browser. The same url pasted outside the iframe works perfectly.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" ng-src="{{getChangeYouTubeLink(companyDetails.youTubeLink)}}"></iframe><br>
{{getChangeYouTubeLink(companyDetails.youTubeLink)}}
```

[you see this when you inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZsow.png)

Do you have idea why it happens?

Comment: the problem is $sce, which is a protection from XSS, and that the link needs to be added to the whitelist. You can use $sce for this.

Comment: have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163152/angularjs-ng-src-inside-of-iframe

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the case!